# Removing duplicates without creating new list

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I need to remove the duplicates in 2ways, one being able to create a new list which i have done by:

```
def remove_extras(lst):
    new_list = []
    for number in list:
       if number not in new_list:
           new_list.append(number)
    return new_list
```

I need a second method where i do not create a new list (order doesn't need to be preserved). I tried using set but it is not the same list as the original one hence doesn't pass the test. anyone has any hints or solutions? thanks

Comment: Do you know how to remove an element from a list?  That would come in handy here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse your function and use slice assignment:

```
lst[:] = remove_extras(lst)
```

More established ways to remove duplicates can be used in the same way:

```
lst[:] = list(set(lst))  # order not preserved
lst[:] = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))  # order preserved
```

`lst` will be the same `list` object afterwards.

Comment: Why create a temporary list?

Comment: @StefanPochmann I wasn't aware you could use any ol' iterator to assign to the slice. I'll leave it as is since the main points of the mutating nature of the slice assignment and the different methods effect on order preservation are clear anyway. I'll leave it as is...

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

```
old_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3]

# create a new list
new_list = list(set(old_list))

# modify old list
old_list = list(set(old_list))
```

Comment: That makes a new list as well

Answer (score 0):

```
def remove(lst):
    seen = set()
    def unseen():
        for val in lst:
            if not val in seen:
                yield val
                seen.add(val)
    lst[:] = unseen()
    return lst
```

input :

```
l = [1,4,2,5,2,2]
```

Output :

```
remove(l)
print l
[1, 4, 2, 5]
```

Comment: @schwobaseggl, Edited

Answer (score 0):

If you need the new list to literally be the same list, try

```
data[:] = list(set(data))
```

By using the slice operator on the assignment, the list gets updated in place, rather than creating a new list

Comment: @StefanPochmann I think I fixed them both.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst[:] = set(lst)
```

Demo:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> lst[:] = set(lst)
>>> lst
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you specifically asked to not create a new `list` object, you can iterate over the set of items in the list, and remove instances from the list where the count of the item is greater than 1.

```
x_list = [1,1,2,2,3,3]

for x in set(x_list):
    for i in range(1, x_list.count(x)):
        x_list.remove(x)

x_list
[1, 2, 3]
```